# Why is while loop not exiting when conditions = false

Tags: java, while-loop

I've got a loop running and when it reaches the the else statement it should stop running. When I debug the boolean power does update but it still enters the loop. I know I could use System.Exit(0); or a break;  but I would understand the logic behind why it would keep running with false conditions?

```
public class Mmu {      
    //code omitted
    public static final Mmu MMU = new Mmu();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MMU.runProcesses();
        //code omitted
    }
        private Mmu() {
            //code omitted 
        }
    protected void runProcesses(){
        boolean power= false; // running processes,  normally this would start as false but I changed to test
        boolean twoFinished = false;
        boolean oneFinished = false;
        while (power = true) { //still entering this when power = false why
            twoFinished = MMU.processTwo.finished();
            oneFinished = MMU.processOne.finished();
            if (oneFinished = false) {
                MMU.processOne.thread();
            } else if (twoFinished = false) {
                MMU.processTwo.thread();
            } else {
                power = false;
                System.out.println("All processes Finished");
                //System.exit(0);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice in advance.

Comment: `power = true` is assignment, not comparison ;). You need `power == true`, or just `while(power)`.

Comment: `=` is assignment operator and `==` is comparison operator

Comment: `while (power == true) ` note double `==`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
while (power = true)
```

Is *always* `true` since you're assigning and not comparing.

Write:

```
while(power)
```

instead.

---

The expression of the assignment returns the **assigned** value.

That's why we don't like to use `==` when we compare `boolean`s, it might lead to this kind of mistakes. You can simply write `if(someBoolean)` instead of `if(someBoolean == true)`.

Comment: Note: The OP has the same issue in the `if` and `else-if` conditions

Comment: Just to explain to the person, this also would work:
while (power == true)

Comment: Thanks and just to clarify also in if statments should be   if(power == true)

Answer (score 5):

`while (power = true)`  here your are using assigning operator and assigning `power = true` again. Use `while(power)`